# How to Do NSlog in Swift - 2.0

Tags: constraints, iso, autolayout

i have a Query Here is the My code...

```
  -(void)hello{
     NSLog(@"there is nothing to show")
}
```

Comment: can't we do things using nib or story board to handle autolayout

Comment: I also have a same problem When i animate view its y Position is change....  please any one help how i fixed it...

Comment: Looking at the keywords of your question I am not sure what the question is. Please clarify.

To print a message to the console in Swift use print() or println().

Answer (score 0):

In Swift strings are not written with an @ before

```
-(void)hello{
     NSLog("there is nothing to show")
}
```

You can also use print(), but I always use NSLog, because you can easily redirect NSLog to a file.